# "No input files" running C program

Tags: command-line

When i tried to run `hello program` of C on the terminal the following error comes:

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello
gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I had the same problem after having saved file in **jEdit** text editor (I wrote the filename in it). Removed file. Created via **nano**. Profit.
Maybe the problem was with encoding, but to be honest, I don't know. Just try this. If it'll work then update your Question or answer on this comment.

Comment: I don't think this is unclear, and I've voted to reopen it. The problem is that `hello.c` isn't in the current directory, which [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/575447/22949) explains well and in a way that is still (and will continue to be) useful. This might turn out to be a duplicate of something and merit reclosure as a duplicate, but I don't think any other close reasons apply--or ever applied--to it.

Answer (score 12):

The clue is in the `No such file or directory`; it can't find the right file. Either...

- You're not in the same directory as your `hello.c` file. `cd` to the right directory, or use provide `gcc` with the path to the file:

  ```
  gcc /home/oli/Desktop/hello.c -o hello
  ```

  Note the same applies to the `-o` output path. If you leave it as `hello` it will try to write to the current working directory (`/home/$USER/` by default). Either change directory or provide a full path.
- Or you've called it `HellO.C` (Ubuntu's filesystems are case sensitive).
- `hello.c` never existed. Perhaps it was just a figment of our collective imaginations; perhaps you forgot to save it; perhaps it's called something else completely.

This is the [second time you've posted about path issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572246/i-am-new-user-of-ubutu-os-i-tried-to-install-tar-gz-file-but-whenever-i-try-to). It's something you'll learn but yeah, commands don't just work globally and not all files live in the same directory. You have to specify where stuff is.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the path properly, Whether your c file does exist in this folder or not. For that, you can use **ls** command to list out all the files in this particular folder.

And for seeing the path for the folder, You can use **pwd**.

Hope this will help you. Because to compile the c file you have entered the right command only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using CMakeLists to compile some C programs. I used `#` in the following to comment the rest of flags:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-format -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-function # -Wno-int-to-void-pointer-cast -Wno-self-assign")
```

but it turns out that I can't comment it like that so I just removed the rest (`# -Wno-int-to-void-pointer-cast -Wno-self-assign`) and it compiled.